# Why does modinfo say “could not find module”, yet lsmod claims the module is loaded?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules

According to the man page of `lsmod` the command shows “what kernel modules are currently loaded”.

I wrote a script that uses `modinfo` to show what kernel object (.ko) files are actually in use:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `lsmod | awk '{print $1}' | sed -n '1!p'`; do
echo "###############################$i###############################"
echo ""
modinfo $i
echo ""
echo ""
done
```

Now I found out that `modinfo nvidia` shows the following output:

`ERROR: modinfo: could not find module nvidia`

Do you guys have any explanation for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `nvidia` module is perfectly loaded and working. The problem lies in `modinfo`.

`modinfo` fetch the list of known modules by reading the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.*` files, which are usually updated with `depmod`.

If `depmod -a` has not been run after installing the `nvidia` module, then `modinfo` does not knows about it. This does not prevent anybody from loading the module with `insmod` and `lsmod` will show it just fine if loaded.

Comment: I ran sudo depmod -a but modinfo still does not know about the nvidia module, but lsmod shows it. How can this be?

Comment: @Hakaishin I'm on ubuntu 16.04 with the nvidia-410 drivers installed, and it appears the name of my kernel module is `nvidia_410`. So try `modinfo nvidia_410` or similar.

Comment: Imagine making an OS where you compile in modules and totally forget everything about them and leave it all buggy designed, so you can't see any info about some random subset of the modules?

Answer (score 0):

If you've recently uninstalled your nvidia driver, you may have unistalled the module from your system, but it's still in your initrd. You can check which are in your initrd with `lsinitrd`.  Or just try reinstalling your kernel to see if it no longer shows up in `lsmod`.